# Fail TeamCity build when angular-cli reports errors

Tags: npm, teamcity, angular-cli

I'm trying to configure team city to run angular 5 application build. 
I have powershell step with this script (it's in the build step definition not separate file). `npm run build` runs `ng build`

```
npm install
npm run build
```

For some reason even if `ng build` fails team city build won't fail. Status code from `npm run` is not propagated back to powershell.

See below screen:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TeamCity Fails the build if got a status code != 0 or when got stderr.

You should add Failure Conditions for verifying that the log has an error.

1. **Edit Configuration Settings**  -> **Failure Conditions** -> **Add failure condition**
2. Select **Fail build on specific text in build log**
3. Secelt options **Contains** and **exact text**. Set "npm ERR"
4. in **Failure message** write "Error was found in build log"
5. save

[image]

Now your build will be FAILED if build log contains this text.

Also, check **an error message is logged by build runner**

Comment: You won't believe how many hours I spent trying to make npm and powershell propagate I totally missed this functionality and we don't need anything more than this. Thanks a lot !